# trying to sum up the amount of children a parent has in a 2d array and also adding a field all the cells has

Tags: php, recursion

hey there I've been trying to solve this for about 3 days now with no avail.

I have a 2d array that looks like:

```
$testObject = array(
    array(
        "id"=> 1,
        "parentID"=> 0,
        "insuCount"=> 300,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
    ),
    array(
        "id"=> 21,
        "parentID"=> 1,
        "insuCount"=> 136,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
    ),
    array(
        "id"=> 52,
        "parentID"=> 21,
        "insuCount"=> 99,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
    )
);
```

The array has a children/parent it also has insuCount, totalInsuCount, childrenCount. i am trying to add up the issuCount from bottom of the hierarchy to the top parent and set the result in totalInsuCount,

Also it will count nested children, like the top parent in my situation has 2 children.

So basically my correct array should look something like:

```
$testObject = array(
    array(
        "id"=> 1,
        "parentID"=> 0,
        "insuCount"=> 300,
        "totalInsuCount"=> 535,
        "childrenCount" => 2
    ),
    array(
        "id"=> 21,
        "parentID"=> 1,
        "insuCount"=> 136,
        "totalInsuCount"=> 235,
        "childrenCount" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id"=> 52,
        "parentID"=> 21,
        "insuCount"=> 99,
        "totalInsuCount"=> 300,
        "childrenCount" => 0
    )
);
```

Anyone has a clue how would i do that, I've been at it for about 3 days now cant figure out how.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to transform your array into array with keys equal to your IDs. It will allow you to access any element directly by ID:

```
$testObject = array(
     1 => array(
        "id"=> 1,
        "parentID"=> 0,
        "insuCount"=> 300,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
     ),
     21 => array(
        "id"=> 21,
        "parentID"=> 1,
        "insuCount"=> 136,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
     ),
     52 => array(
        "id"=> 52,
        "parentID"=> 21,
        "insuCount"=> 99,
        "totalInsuCount"=> '',
        "childrenCount" => ''
     )
);
```

this is pretty obvious to implement. So i will leave the solution to you.

And now we can easily calculate counts for all parents:

```
foreach ($testObject as $id => &$data){

    $parentId = $data['parentID'];
    while ($parentId && isset($testObject[$parentId])){
        $parentData = &$testObject[$parentId];

        $parentData["childrenCount"]++;
        $parentData["totalInsuCount"] += $data["insuCount"];

        $parentId = $parentData['parentID'];
    }

    $data["totalInsuCount"] += $data["insuCount"];
}

print_r($testObject);
```

**UPDATE**

Test that any children was counted and belongs to some root entry:

```
$totalChildren = 0;
foreach ($testObject as $data){
    //sum all childrens of root elements
    if (!$data['parentID']) $totalChildren += $data["childrenCount"] + 1;
}   

echo 'Children counted: ' .$totalChildren;
echo "<br>";
echo 'Total elements: ' .sizeof($testObject);
```

Also i had to prepare the initial array as some entries are self referenced:

```
$newTestObject = array();
foreach ($testObject as $data){
    if ($data['id'] == $data['parentID']) $data['parentID'] = 0;
    $newTestObject[$data['id']] = $data;
}

$testObject = $newTestObject;
```

Comment: Yours works pretty nice however it doesnt go to the children of childres, i run it on my array and the a parent that has close to 300 none direct children has only 72.

Comment: Perhaps you have something wrong with children dependencies. Can you pastebin your full data? http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Getting it one sec seems pastbin is down, here is a gisthub:
https://gist.github.com/yanivkalfa/5708038

Comment: totalInsuCount - it count them correctly however, childrenCount wont work.

Comment: Why are you sure that `childrenCount` is invalid? Seems correct to me. BTW in your data some entries has parentID == id, i set parentID=0 for whose entries.

Comment: Updated the answer with the test. I am still sure that everything is correct.

Comment: Claustrofob, Your answer is perfectly correct, i just checked and its seem i was a monkey .... Sorry for the confusion. nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mind I have outgrown PHP. So the following is simplistic code.

1. Split the task in todos and dones parts.
2. While todos not empty repeat:
3. Search a candidate in todos that is noone's parent in the todos.
4. If found initialize the cummulative fields. Check the dones whether this is someones parent, and accumulate. *(Equivalent to checking all, as in todo it is noone's parent.)* Remove from todos.
5. Error in data: If no candidate found in the non-empty todos, someone is its own grand-parent.

So:

```
$todo = array(); // Array of indices into $testObject.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($testObject); ++$i) {
    $todo[] = $i;
}

while (count($todo) > 0) {
    $didOne = FALSE;
    foreach ($todo as $i) {
        $id = $testObject[$i]["id"];
        $isAtBottom = TRUE;
        foreach ($todo as $j) {
            if ($j != $i && $testObject[$j]["parentID"] == $id) {
                $isAtBottom = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($isAtBottom) {
            $didOne = TRUE;
            $testObject[$i]["totalInsuCount"] = $testObject[$i]["insuCount"];
            $testObject[$i]["childrenCount"] = 0;
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($testObject); ++$k) { // Walk done items
                if ($testObject[$k]["id"] != $id 
                    && $testObject[$k]["parentID"] == $id) {
                    $testObject[$i]["totalInsuCount"] +=
                        $testObject[$k]["totalInsuCount"];
                    ++$testObject[$i]["childrenCount"];
                }
            }
            array_splice($todo, $i, 1);
            //break; // As $todo changed, simply next while
        }
    }
    if (!$didOne) {
        error_log("Cyclic dependency");
    }
}
print("<pre>\n");
print_r($testObject);
print("\n</pre>\n");
```

Comment: An issue is that `$todo` should share the elements of `$testObject`. Maybe `$todo` should only contain indices to `$testObject`.

Comment: I dont know what you meant by share the elements of $testObject, How ever is there any chance to see a working copy with any language

Comment: Okay, I've turned pseudo-code in actual correct PHP. Probably not the nicest code. Hope it is readable.

Comment: The break after `array_splice` seems unneeded.

Comment: Thanks joop for the help but i've already used @claustrofob 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda bugs me that I can't just write comments... anyway.

Your last array entry doesn't make sense to me. count = 99 + 0 children values = 300? How should the count work?

Comment: The count should go up.. the hierarchy so basically the cell with the id 52 is the child of 21, so it will add the insuCount (99), with its father, which is 136, so 99+ 136 = 235 , 21 is the children of 1, so we will add 99+136+300.. etcs, as for childrenCount. id 1 has 1 direct children and 1 none direct children(children of a children) and therefore has 2, 21 has 1 just 1 direct children.